# why my bootstrap nav-menu doesn't appear correctly

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, bootstrap-grid

i'm trying to create a wordpress theme but i'm getting this problem with the navbar from bootstrap "currently i just want to show the navbar without converting it to wordpress i mean i want it static for now not dynamic"

this is how it appear in the browser 
[appear in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFvaV.jpg)

this is my header.php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> >
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" >
    <title><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>"
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
```

and this is my functions.php file

```
<?php 

/**
 * Add My Custom Styles
 */
function elzero_add_styles(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri()."/css/bootstrap.min.css");
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome-css', get_template_directory_uri()."/css/fontawesome.min.css");
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main-css', get_template_directory_uri()."/css/main.css");

}

/**
 * Add My Custom Scripts
 */
function elzero_add_scripts(){
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', includes_url().'/js/jquery/jquery.js', array(),false,true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'),false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main-js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/main.js', array(),false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'htmlshiv', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/htmlshiv.js');
    wp_script_add_data( 'htmlshiv','conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'respond', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/respond.js');
    wp_script_add_data( 'respond','conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

}
/**
 * Add Actions
 */

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','elzero_add_styles');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','elzero_add_scripts');
add_action( 'init','elzero_add_menu' );


/**
 * Add MENUS
 */
function elzero_add_menu(){

}



?>
```

this is the page source code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" >
    <title>Elzero</title>
    <link rel="pingback" href="http://localhost/wordpress/xmlrpc.php"
    <meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/2.4\/72x72\/","ext":".png","svgUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/2.4\/svg\/","svgExt":".svg","source":{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/localhost\/wordpress\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.9.4"}};
            !function(a,b,c){function d(a,b){var c=String.fromCharCode;l.clearRect(0,0,k.width,k.height),l.fillText(c.apply(this,a),0,0);var d=k.toDataURL();l.clearRect(0,0,k.width,k.height),l.fillText(c.apply(this,b),0,0);var e=k.toDataURL();return d===e}function e(a){var b;if(!l||!l.fillText)return!1;switch(l.textBaseline="top",l.font="600 32px Arial",a){case"flag":return!(b=d([55356,56826,55356,56819],[55356,56826,8203,55356,56819]))&&(b=d([55356,57332,56128,56423,56128,56418,56128,56421,56128,56430,56128,56423,56128,56447],[55356,57332,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56418,8203,56128,56421,8203,56128,56430,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56447]),!b);case"emoji":return b=d([55357,56692,8205,9792,65039],[55357,56692,8203,9792,65039]),!b}return!1}function f(a){var c=b.createElement("script");c.src=a,c.defer=c.type="text/javascript",b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)}var g,h,i,j,k=b.createElement("canvas"),l=k.getContext&&k.getContext("2d");for(j=Array("flag","emoji"),c.supports={everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0},i=0;i<j.length;i++)c.supports[j[i]]=e(j[i]),c.supports.everything=c.supports.everything&&c.supports[j[i]],"flag"!==j[i]&&(c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&c.supports[j[i]]);c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&!c.supports.flag,c.DOMReady=!1,c.readyCallback=function(){c.DOMReady=!0},c.supports.everything||(h=function(){c.readyCallback()},b.addEventListener?(b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",h,!1),a.addEventListener("load",h,!1)):(a.attachEvent("onload",h),b.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===b.readyState&&c.readyCallback()})),g=c.source||{},g.concatemoji?f(g.concatemoji):g.wpemoji&&g.twemoji&&(f(g.twemoji),f(g.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
    display: inline !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 1em !important;
    width: 1em !important;
    margin: 0 .07em !important;
    vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/elzero/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=4.9.4' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='fontawesome-css-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/elzero/css/fontawesome.min.css?ver=4.9.4' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='main-css-css'  href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/elzero/css/main.css?ver=4.9.4' type='text/css' media='all' />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/elzero/js/htmlshiv.js?ver=4.9.4'></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/elzero/js/respond.js?ver=4.9.4'></script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/' />
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://localhost/wordpress/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.9.4" />
</head>
<body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>




    <div class="footer text-center">
        Copy Rights &copy; Reserved 2018
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes//js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=4.9.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/elzero/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=4.9.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/elzero/js/main.js?ver=4.9.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.9.4'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: screenshot of your `functions.php` tell us nothing related to your questions. also, instead of providing screenshot of `header.php` file, add it's content to your question

Comment: ok what should i include ?

Comment: code from `header.php` file

Comment: ok i have edited the post please check it out :)

Comment: just tried your header.php and it's seems fine i think you should check if the script and css are loaded correctly or not (you can see it from page source) and if they are loaded correctly then you should check if you have any html tag not closed

Comment: it seems ok for the scripts and for the tag 

i can't find where is the problem 
i have included the page source in the post please check it out :)

Comment: oh i have found the problem i've been using bootstrap v4 and the classes are for bootstrap 3.3.7 shame on me :D
thanks guys for your help